# push ViewController without storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I try to push a view controller from the main ViewController like this (Swift 4):

```
@objc func childAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Child button tapped")
    let vc = childDetailViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

The text is printed, but the viewController is not pushed. What did I missed?

Comment: you need to set rootViewController first inside of AppDelegate and than you able to navigate between the view controllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` do

```
let fir = FirstVC()
self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: fir)
```

Then this

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

should work

Comment: Thanks, it works now. The problem was in AppDelegate, I had this line: `self.window?.rootViewController = mainViewController()`

Comment: That is a bad way to manage your app navigation. Don't do any navigation related job in your `AppDelegate` except initial setup. It is a bad practice.

Comment: @PavloBoiko who told you that ?? this is the correct way to init the app with a navigation , your code makes a present that it's not related to op's current case of push/pop

Comment: @Sh_Khan, your code makes sense if that is `FirstVC`, but not on master/child scope. I was asking @user9865814 to make `present` to detect kind of issue.

Comment: it's easy also to insert the navigation in the middle , but if this solved the op issue then no need to suggest it

Answer (score 5):

Possible that `self.navigationController` is `nil`.

Try to present it: `self.present(vc, animated: true)`

**UPD**

Also if it does not help, try temporary change your `childDetailViewController` to `UIViewController()` and see what happens. If you see the empty white screen after tap then the problem is on childDetailViewController

Comment: Thanks, It works with `self.present(vc, animated: true)`

Comment: @user9865814, so check your navigation stack. Keep in mind that when you `present` some controller from navigation controller you losing your navigation stack. So try use just `push` and `pop` in your stack

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode 11 you might have noticed that along with the default files like above, a new file is created named as SceneDelegate.swift. From iOS 13 and later, SceneDelegate takes up some responsibilites from AppDelegate. In particular related to UIWindow from AppDelegate is now UIScene in SceneDelegate. An app can have more than one scene which mostly handles application interface and app content. So, the SceneDelegate is responsible for what’s displayed on the screen in terma of UI and data.

```
var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
   
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let vc = ViewController()
    let navigationView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationView
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```